# Find values of a DataFrame that are between the values of two columns on other DataFrame

Tags: r

I have two dataframes. dataframe_A contains users and a given value:

```r
dfA <- structure(list(User = 1:5, Value = c(54L, 12L, 7L, 123L, 74L)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
dfA
#>   User Value
#> 1    1    54
#> 2    2    12
#> 3    3     7
#> 4    4   123
#> 5    5    74
```

dfB contains ranges of values and a multiplier I want to add to dfA:

```r
dfB <- structure(list(Min = c(0L, 50L, 80L, 100L, 120L), 
                      Max = c(50L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 1000L), 
                      Mult = c(0, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
dfB
#>   Min  Max Mult
#> 1   0   50  0.0
#> 2  50   80  0.5
#> 3  80  100  0.8
#> 4 100  120  1.0
#> 5 120 1000  1.2
```

So the desired result is to add the multiplier found in dfB to dfB:

```r
dfA
    User Value  Mult 
[1]    1    54   0.5
[2]    2    12     0
[3]    3     7     0
[4]    4   123   1.2
[5]    5    74   0.5
```

I have tried this code (which works with individual values), but doesntwork in a dataframe:

```r
dfA$Mult <- print(subset(dfB, dfA$Value > dfB$Min & dfA$Value < dfB$Max)$Mult)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the desired `Mult` for a value of 50? Looks to me like either `Min` or `Max` should have 1 subtracted for them, or, at least, it should be specified whether the edge cases fall into the lower or higher bracket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` in base R for each `value` in `dfA`.

```
dfA$mult <- sapply(dfA$Value, function(x) with(dfB, Mult[x >= Min & x <= Max]))

dfA
#  User Value mult
#1    1    54  0.5
#2    2    12  0.0
#3    3     7  0.0
#4    4   123  1.2
#5    5    74  0.5
```

**data**

```
dfA <- structure(list(User = 1:5, Value = c(54L, 12L, 7L, 123L, 74L)), 
       row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dfB <- structure(list(Min = c(0L, 50L, 80L, 100L, 120L), Max = c(50L, 
       80L, 100L, 120L, 1000L), Mult = c(0, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2)), 
       class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the data reprex, @RonakShah. PietroAiorta, this would have been good to include in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

If the intervals in `dfB` form a partition of a larger range by cutting it up in sequential intervals as in the example, we can also use `findInterval` or `cut` to match the values in `dfA` to the intervals in `dfB`. With `findInterval`:

```r
findInterval(x = dfA$Value, vec = c(dfB$Min[1], dfB$Max))
#> [1] 2 1 1 5 2
```

Combined with the creation of a new `Mult` column in `dfA`, we could write:

```r
dfA$Mult <- with(dfB, Mult[findInterval(x = dfA$Value, vec = c(Min[1], Max))])

dfA
#>   User Value Mult
#> 1    1    54  0.5
#> 2    2    12  0.0
#> 3    3     7  0.0
#> 4    4   123  1.2
#> 5    5    74  0.5
```

**Disclaimer:** the use of `findInterval` becomes more tedious if the intervals in `dfB` do not line up nicely, in which case Ronak's approach might be more straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

Some tidyverse solutions. The first two do cross-joins between the two tables - which may certainly be VERY expensive with large tables - and then filter down the result to what should be the one row per original `dfA` row where the `Value` is in a `dfB` range. The last will certainly be faster, as it immediately filters down `dfB`, once for each `Value`, and then just defines the new `dfA` variable using the filtered and stacked `Mult`s - but it does some trippy things with a parallel mapping nested inside another mapping, all inside the `mutate()`, so I bet it's hard to read for those that aren't very familiar with `purrr`. But I'd love to see some comparative benchmarks!

Note also that the task is unclear re: edge cases between the `Mult` brackets - if a value is 50, is the `Mult` 0 or 0.5? Here I go with the higher `Mult`.

```r
dfA <- structure(list(User = 1:5, Value = c(54L, 12L, 7L, 123L, 74L)), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dfB <- structure(list(Min = c(0L, 50L, 80L, 100L, 120L), 
                      Max = c(50L, 80L, 100L, 120L, 1000L),
                      Mult = c(0, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2)), 
                 class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))

library(tidyverse)

crossing(dfA, dfB) %>% 
  filter(Value >= Min, Value < Max) %>% 
  select(-Min, -Max)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    User Value  Mult
#>   <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1    54   0.5
#> 2     2    12   0  
#> 3     3     7   0  
#> 4     4   123   1.2
#> 5     5    74   0.5

# Slightly more verbose and yet slightly DRYer
crossing(dfA, dfB) %>% 
  filter(list(Value, Min, Max - 1) %>% pmap_lgl(between)) %>% 
  select(-Min, -Max)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>    User Value  Mult
#>   <int> <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1    54   0.5
#> 2     2    12   0  
#> 3     3     7   0  
#> 4     4   123   1.2
#> 5     5    74   0.5

# Definitely faster, and DRY, and yet more verbose as well as harder to read
dfA %>% mutate(
  Mult = Value %>% map_dbl(
    ~ dfB %>% 
      filter(list(.x, Min, Max - 1) %>% pmap_lgl(between)) %>% 
      pull(Mult)
  )
)
#>   User Value Mult
#> 1    1    54  0.5
#> 2    2    12  0.0
#> 3    3     7  0.0
#> 4    4   123  1.2
#> 5    5    74  0.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
dfA <- structure(list(User = 1:5, Value = c(54L, 12L, 7L, 123L, 74L)), 
             row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

dfB <- structure(list(Min = c(0L, 50L, 80L, 100L, 120L), Max = c(50L, 80L, 
             100L, 120L,1000L), Mult = c(0, 0.5, 0.8, 1, 1.2)), 
             class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
# we add a mult column to dfA and set all its values to NA
dfA$mult = NA
# now we create a function which takes input as a single value from dfA
# and returns the desired multiplier from dfB
mult_fun = function(x)
{
  for (j in 1:nrow(dfB)) {
    if(x > dfB$Min[j] & x < dfB$Max[j]) {
      return(dfB$Mult[j])
    }
  }
}
# now we use mult_fun and gets multiplier for every value in dfA
for (i in 1:nrow(dfA)) {
  dfA$mult[i] = mult_fun(dfA$Value[i])
}
```

Output:

```
> dfA
  User Value mult
1    1    54  0.5
2    2    12  0.0
3    3     7  0.0
4    4   123  1.2
5    5    74  0.5
```